# Name of a polynomial basis

Tags: polynomials

Does anybody know if the set of polynomials
 $\{ 1,x,x^2+2,x^3+3x,x^4+4x^2+6,{x}^{5}+5\,{x}^{3}+10\,x,{x}^{6}+6\,{x}^{4}+15\,{x}^{2}+20,\ldots \}$
appear in the literature? I am curious what they are called if they do appear?
 (Note: I am not asking what the pattern of the coefficients is. The answer to that question is rows of the classical Pascal triangle.) Please give me a reference if you know where I can find them. 
Thanks.

Comment: I guess you could call them the "polynomial part" of $(x+x^{-1})^n$.

Comment: Have you checked the OEIS?

Comment: If you'd like to generate these in *Mathematica*:  `q = 6;
Total@(Cases[myPoly = Expand[(x + 1/x)^q], 
    a_ x^n_?Positive -> a x^n] \[Union] Cases[myPoly, a_Integer -> a])`